# I need to change date in CSV file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have sample data file (csv) as below and required to generate large data from sample file. for that i need to change date (DD) in timestamp and run for loop to generate more data.

```
14/03/2017 00:05:58,General2,General3,General4,General5,General6,General7
```

Comment: What do you want to change the date _to_? A pistachio?

Comment: required to generate monthly data. Hence required to change date with another DD. like 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the possibilities in bash (tried on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

Put your csv in a file called yourfile.csv (or change this code), then run this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$1
for i in `seq 1 30`; do
        NEWDATE=`date -d"${DATE}+${i}day" +'%d/%m/%Y'`
        while read line; do
                echo $line | sed -u -r "s#^.{10}#${NEWDATE}#"
        done <yourfile.csv
done
```

It will generate +30 days for EACH input line, so you only need to have file with 1 line. Oh and it accepts date as parameter and will generate +30 days of data starting from that date.

Update for slowness:
Try this, maybe it works faster for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$1
let i=0
while read line; do
        let i=(i++ % 30)
        NEWDATE=`date -d"${DATE}+${i}day" +'%d/%m/%Y'`
        echo $line | sed -u -r "s#^.{10}#${NEWDATE}#"
done <yourfile.csv
```

It will be 1M row will make 1M rows, not 1M makes 30M.

Comment: Your bash script is working perfectly fine. but its taking too much time. Could you please help me with perl or python script.

Comment: How many lines did you have in your csv file? It works practically instantly for me, and I had just 4 lines. Remember, it makes 30 lines of csv for each 1 line in the file, so if you kept a large csv, it would create a huge one.

Comment: 1M row we have in sample CSV file

Comment: Well then use just the first 10 lines of it maybe?

Comment: Added another solution, which does not generate new lines, but changes all lines in existing file.

Answer (score 0):

To simply change the days in the date to some fixed value like 15, you can do

```
sed 's/[0-9]*/15/' your.csv
```

If you want to change it in that file, add the `-i` option if your `sed` supports it.

If you want to automate this for all days in many month, better use another tool like `python` or `perl`.

**Update:**
Or have some `sed` fun:

```
sed -n 'p;x;s/^/0123456789_/;H;g
  :a
  s#\(.\)\(/.*\1\)\(.\)#\3\2\3#
  s/^0_/10/;s/^1_/20/;s/^2_/30/
  /^31.0[46]/s/1/2/;s#^32/0\(.\)\(.*\1\)\(.\)#01/0\3\2\3#
  P;\#^01/08#!ba' sample.csv
```

This multiplies each line with each day starting from the given `14/03` to the `01/08`. Sorry for drinking too much.

Comment: Could you please share the example please

Comment: Share what example? For the automatization? Then you need to define what you need exactly.

Comment: yes, for automation

Comment: 15/03/2017 00:05:58,General2,General3,General4,General5,General6,General7

Just required to change DD rest values will be same.

Comment: Only for a couple of days or for each day from March 14th to August 1st or what? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I need data of  each day from 14 March to 1 August in CSV file.

Comment: Not necessary to use fully blown programming language for this.

Comment: @Gnudiff You are right. Updated my answer. (-;

Comment: @Philippos Could you please help me with perl or python script which can do the thing very fast. Bash script is working but very slow. It is generating 1M row in 18Minutes.